# How can I use Docker without sudo?

Tags: docker

On Docker's documentation pages, all example commands are shown without `sudo`, like this one:

```
docker ps
```

On Ubuntu, the binary is called `docker.io`. It also does not work without `sudo`:

```
sudo docker.io ps
```

How can I configure Docker so that I don't need to prefix every Docker command with `sudo`?

Comment: Don't forget to enable ufw ;)

Comment: On Ubuntu 14.04 [there is](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty-updates/amd64/docker.io/filelist) also 'docker' binary.

Comment: @anatolytechtonik I also used 'docker' instead of  'docker.io' in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Comment: Recommended installation is _not_  the docker in default ubuntu repos; instead, instructions here ( https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/ubuntulinux/ ), recommend using the docker repo. Remove all the existing docker stuff, and verify you're getting the one from the right source: `apt-cache policy docker-engine` (apt url should be from dockerproject.org)

Comment: How about an alias:?  That way, you still use sudo, with password protection.   alias docker="sudo docker "

Comment: Yeah, until Docker implements policykit or something similar I'd strongly recommend using an alias, otherwise you might as well just run everything as root.

Comment: sudo chmod 666 /var/run/docker.sock

Comment: What junk is this for requiring root to do simple things such as `docker info`. Like `docker info` needs raw access to all my file and devices and ports to run.

Comment: @Flimm Your flag says "This is an answer that is probably wrong".  If it's a *wrong answer* then you should just flag the comment for deletion.

Comment: @TechnicalKeera that breaks a bit because then the docker daemon can't talk to the socket.  It also will not stick, it'll be recreated at next boot as a different user so the solution proposed will fail.  If you want to bypass sudo for docker you SHOULD put your user into the `docker` group if you want unrestricted execution access for the user - it's a security risk to do that though, so running `sudo` on your docker commands is the way you *should* be handling things which need run as an admin.

Answer (score 1472, accepted):

Good news: the new Docker version 19.03 (currently experimental) will be able to run rootless negating the problems that can occur using a root user. No more messing with elevated permissions, root, and anything that might open up your machine when you did not want to.

Video about this from [[DockerCon 2019] Hardening Docker daemon with Rootless mode](https://www.slideshare.net/AkihiroSuda/dockercon-2019-hardening-docker-daemon-with-rootless-mode)

> A few Caveats to the rootless Docker mode
>
> Docker engineers say the rootless mode cannot be considered a replacement for the complete suite of Docker engine features. Some limitation to the rootless mode include:
>
> - cgroups resource controls, apparmor security profiles, checkpoint/restore, overlay networks etc. do not work on rootless mode.
> - Exposing ports from containers currently requires manual socat helper process.
> - Only Ubuntu-based distros support overlay filesystems in rootless mode.
> - Rootless mode is currently only provided for nightly builds that may not be as stable as you are used to.

---

As of Docker 19.3 this is obsolete (and more dangerous than need be):

The [Docker manual](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/ubuntulinux/#/create-a-docker-group) has this to say about it:

> **Giving non-root access**
>
> The docker daemon always runs as the root user, and since Docker version 0.5.2, the docker daemon binds to a Unix socket instead of a TCP port. By default that Unix socket is owned by the user root, and so, by default, you can access it with sudo.
>
> Starting in version 0.5.3, if you (or your Docker installer) create a Unix group called docker and add users to it, then the docker daemon will make the ownership of the Unix socket read/writable by the docker group when the daemon starts. The docker daemon must always run as the root user, but if you run the docker client as a user in the docker group then you don't need to add sudo to all the client commands. As of 0.9.0, you can specify that a group other than docker should own the Unix socket with the -G option.
>
> **Warning: The docker group (or the group specified with -G) is root-equivalent; see [Docker Daemon Attack Surface details](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/security/#/docker-daemon-attack-surface) and this blogpost on [Why we don't let non-root users run Docker in CentOS, Fedora, or RHEL](https://www.projectatomic.io/blog/2015/08/why-we-dont-let-non-root-users-run-docker-in-centos-fedora-or-rhel/)**  (thanks michael-n).
>
> In the recent release of the [experimental rootless mode on GitHub](https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/master/docs/rootless.md), engineers mention rootless mode allows running dockerd as an unprivileged user, using user_namespaces(7), mount_namespaces(7), network_namespaces(7).
>
> Users need to run dockerd-rootless.sh instead of dockerd.
>
> ```
> $ dockerd-rootless.sh --experimental
> ```
>
> As Rootless mode is experimental, users need to always run dockerd-rootless.sh with –experimental.

---

Important to read: [post-installation steps for Linux](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/linux-postinstall/) (it also links to [Docker Daemon Attack Surface details](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/security/#/docker-daemon-attack-surface)).

> **Manage Docker as a non-root user**
>
> The docker daemon binds to a Unix socket instead of a TCP port. By default that Unix socket is owned by the user root and other users can only access it using sudo. The docker daemon always runs as the root user.
>
> If you don’t want to use sudo when you use the docker command, create a Unix group called docker and add users to it. When the docker daemon starts, it makes the ownership of the Unix socket read/writable by the docker group.

---

- Add the `docker` group if it doesn't already exist:

  ```
   sudo groupadd docker
  ```
- Add the connected user "$USER" to the `docker` group. Change the user name to match your preferred user if you do not want to use your current user:

  ```
   sudo gpasswd -a $USER docker
  ```
- Either do a `newgrp docker` or log out/in to activate the changes to groups.
- You can use

  ```
   docker run hello-world
  ```

  to check if you can run Docker without `sudo`.

Comment: @Chechus "You need to log out and log back in again for this to take effect." has been there for over a year?

Comment: @Rinzwind Could you consider any several security implication that this may have to the host system to remark on the answer?

Comment: Isn't that the most insecure architecture for production? I must be missing something

Comment: @matt not the "most" insecure. See the link for some things on that: "First of all, only trusted users should be allowed to control your Docker daemon.". If you use it with a webserver (ie. as an API) you have another layer of problems.

Comment: Yeah, but every privileged process opens up potential for exploit. Is docker hooking that deep into the operating system to really mandate that level of privileges?

Comment: `newgrp docker` didn't work for me, i had to log out.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that this gives that user _unrestricted, non-password protected root access_. See details of the [vulnerability here](https://fosterelli.co/privilege-escalation-via-docker.html)

Comment: @ChrisFoster that's why there is a bit fat warning in there. But it is also set up such that is someone can exploit this they got bigger problems ;-)

Comment: This: "If you are on Ubuntu 14.04 and up use docker.io instead: sudo service docker.io restart" is not correct for Ubuntu 16.04 server edition. The service is called "docker" simply. Installed docker via Xenials ordinary apt sources using sudo apt-get install docker.io though.

Comment: you do NOT need to restart the docker daemon for this change to take place!! just have the user that you just added log out then back in

Comment: more on the security vulnerability this 'solution' presents, here: https://www.projectatomic.io/blog/2015/08/why-we-dont-let-non-root-users-run-docker-in-centos-fedora-or-rhel/

Comment: @Tommy This worked for me also, but I suspect that it was because the docker group already existed. If the docker group does not exist before starting the server, I'd bet you do have to restart it, or at least `systemctl reload docker`.

Comment: Note that restarting the docker service will stop all containers running being run. It's obvious in retrospect, but it's worth warning people about.

Comment: As stated by @Tommy, there should not be a need to restart docker service. Docker service does not care about users, all it receives is an anonymous HTTP request to perform an action. Adding user to the `docker` group allows to access unix socket through which you make the request. That is entirely on the client-side which does not actively run and is not affected by `service docker restart`.

Comment: @Pijusn there removed it.

Comment: if you use `docker login`, you may find that the `.docker` folder created in your home folder, belongs to `root`. thus you would encounter this warning when running docker commands: `WARNING: Error loading config file:/home/myuser/.docker/config.json - stat /home/myuser/.docker/config.json: permission denied`. I made my user's `.docker` folder accessible without sudo like so: `sudo chgrp -hR docker ~/.docker && sudo chown -R myuser ~/.docker`. the `chgrp` didn't seem to help though, so probably I should only recommend the chown step.

Comment: @Tommy, I also had to restart the docker server. Since my docker group did not exist, the file ownership on the /var/run/docker.sock file was root:root. When I restarted the docker server it was root:docker.  Then it worked for me.

Comment: this helped, but the trick was to run @Christian Hujer wrote sudo setfacl -m user:username:rw /var/run/docker.sock

Comment: @BenYitzhaki  I did not want to steal his part of this ;-)

Comment: @Rinzwind didn't really follow the comments, just wasted too much time on this when the answer was on front of me :(

Comment: Followed all the steps mentioned, logged out and in multiple times but that didn't help. Finally did a "sudo service docker restart" and bingo, docker was able to run images without sudo!

Comment: I had to restart Ubunutu. Logging out didn't work.

Comment: Are you saying that as of now I should by default not be encountering the error `Got permission denied while trying...` at all anymore? I am still getting this error on `Docker version 20.10.2, build 20.10.2-0ubuntu1~20.04.2` and I still had to solve it through the `groupadd` procedure.

Comment: sudo chown $USER /var/run/docker.sock it worked for me

Comment: @TanjinAlam I would advide to jnclude  the group too (so `$USER:$USER` ) if the socket has permission 6 (rw) for groups (if lower it does not matter).

Answer (score 432):

To run docker command without `sudo`, you need to add your user (who has root privileges) to docker group. For this run following command:

```
 sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
```

Now, have the user logout then login again. This solution is well explained [here](http://jee-appy.blogspot.com/2016/02/installing-docker-in-virtual-box.html) with proper installation process.

Comment: after add user to group , run this command: sg group_name -c "bash"

Comment: you do not need to restart the OS for this change to take place! That will bomb all running containers! Just have the user that you just added log out then in.

Comment: This is indeed what the [official Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/linux-postinstall/#/manage-docker-as-a-non-root-user) recommends doing to be able to run docker with unprivileged users:

Comment: How is that command different to "sudo gpasswd -a ${USER} docker" in other answer? If at all...

Comment: Could you please add the warning given by the docs: " The docker group [...] is root-equivalent", so people have a chance to think about it

Comment: Same effect as the 2 year older accepted answer, but without the warnings about the security risks

Comment: Still getting: Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get "http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.24/containers/json": dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied

Comment: @Soren Logging out often does not work, restart the machine and try again. Could update the answer with this info.

Comment: requires reboot

Comment: Logging out/in did not work. I did that 3 times and it did not work. Only after system reboot, it worked. Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. Change the answer to say that reboot is needed.

Comment: I don't know why people keep using `usermod`/`useradd` with options instead of `adduser $USER docker`, the friendly and convenient frontend that [Debian recommends](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/system-administrator/ch-sysadmin-users.html#s8.2.1)

Answer (score 158):

The mechanism by which adding a user to group `docker` grants permission to run docker is to get access to the socket of docker at `/var/run/docker.sock`. If the filesystem that contains `/var/run` has been mounted with ACLs enabled, this can also be achieved via ACLs.

```
sudo setfacl -m user:$USER:rw /var/run/docker.sock
```

I'm only including this for completeness.

In general, I recommend to avoid ACLs whenever a good alternative based on groups is available: It is better if the privileges in a system can be understood by looking at group memberships only. Having to scan the file system for ACL entries in order to understand system privileges is an additional burden for security audits.

*Warning 1*: This has the same `root` equivalence as adding `$USER` to the `docker` group. You can still start a container in a way that has `root` access to the host filesystem.

*Warning 2*: ACLs are significantly more difficult for security audits than group-based security. Probably avoid ACLs if possible when you can use groups instead, at least in audit-relevant environments.

Comment: It worked on 16.04

Comment: Much better way imo. The group docker is root-equivalent and that is always a sign of danger. And I don't see any disadvantage to taking ownership of this one file.

Comment: Could you describe which commands should be executed in order to "*get access to the socket of docker at `/var/run/docker.sock`*"?

Comment: @yuval That command is already described in the answer, it's the `setfacl` command.

Comment: @Xerus if I understand correctly, [whoever can write to this socket can get root-equivalent privileges too](https://www.projectatomic.io/blog/2015/08/why-we-dont-let-non-root-users-run-docker-in-centos-fedora-or-rhel/). So giving someone access to this socket via ACL has the same security effect as adding that person to the docker group.

Comment: This solution worker with Ubuntu 18.04 as well. In any case I did sudo groupadd docker and sudo usermod -aG docker $USER as well before of it.

Comment: Do the job for me on Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Worked on Ubuntu 21.04

Comment: worked on 22.04

Comment: This is solid, b/c it doesn't require any shell restarts, so it can be used in the middle of a script and actually work. Yes, like ~all other lazy options, it grants root access, but in cases when you are already using root because _reasons_, it is much simpler than setup and maintenance of rootless docker.

Answer (score 54):

After creating the docker group and adding my user to it with

```bsh
sudo groupadd docker
sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
```

... I still had to give the `/var/run/docker.sock` socket and `/var/run/docker` directory the proper permissions to make it work:

```bsh
sudo chown root:docker /var/run/docker.sock
sudo chown -R root:docker /var/run/docker
```

Logout and login again (with that user) then you'll be able to run docker commands without `sudo`:

```bsh
docker run hello-world
```

BTW: This was fixed in Ubuntu 21.10 and is only necessary for Ubuntu versions lower than that.

Comment: I get `chown: changing ownership of '/var/run/docker/netns/ingress_sbox': Operation not permitted`

Comment: @Soren I just tried it right now again with Ubuntu 20.04 and all my commands from above work fine. If you use the `chown` command with `sudo` you shouldn't get any error messages. Try to reboot, log into the root accout and run the two `chown` commands (no `sudo` needed). Then logout from the root user account and into your normal user account and try to use docker without `sudo`. Does it work now?

Comment: Worked for me with just adding the group and adding the user to the group, but after reboot. Im on Pop!_OS 20.04 LTS. One might want to reboot, try it out and only if it doesnt work use this solution.

Comment: @Soren this is because you are trying to `chown` while the docker daemon is running. Stop docker with `systemctl stop docker` then run the commands of this solution and start it again with `systemctl start docker`

Answer (score 9):

Docker containers need to be run by a superuser. You can add yourself to the `docker` group (e.g. by running `sudo usermod -aG docker $USER`), but this makes it easy for anyone with access to the `$USER` account to gain root access to the machine (e.g. by mounting a root volume in a privileged container).

A more security-conscious way of running Docker containers as a non-root user would be to use [Podman](https://podman.io/). From its website:

> Podman is a daemonless container engine for developing, managing, and running OCI Containers on your Linux System. Containers can either be run as root or in **rootless mode**. Simply put: `alias docker=podman`.

Another alternative is [Singularity](https://sylabs.io/), which is more commonly deployed in HPC environments.

Comment: Please provide info on why docker containers must be run as a root user.

Comment: @GaTechThomas See https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/#manage-docker-as-a-non-root-user. *"The Docker daemon binds to a Unix socket instead of a TCP port. By default that Unix socket is owned by the user root and other users can only access it using sudo. The Docker daemon always runs as the root user."* My knowledge does not go deeper than this.

Comment: Docker can be run without root permisssions. See the section _Run the Docker daemon as a non-root user (Rootless mode)_ https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/rootless/