# How to startup as user (docker)?

Tags: permissions, root, docker

I'm running the ubuntu docker image from my mac. When I do `docker run -it containername` it starts as root. But I want to start as a user instead, I don't want to have to manually do `login username`

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/477551/how-can-i-use-docker-without-sudo/477554#477554

Comment: @Rinzwind I'm not trying to run docker without sudo, I'm trying to launch my ubuntu container and be logged in as a user, instead of as root

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run it as:
docker run --interactive --tty --user $(id -u):$(id -g) containername.

You should have a user already created in dockerfile with same uid/guid.

The already posted link refers to docker daemon which is another matter.