# Why /var/run/docker.sock permissions are changed every time I log out? How can I forbid it?

Tags: permissions, docker, chmod

Everytime after logging in I am getting `permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket` so I need to execute `sudo chmod 777 /var/run/docker.sock` to solve it. I am curious why and how permissions of this file are changed everytime. Also I want to forbid such changes so I don't need to execute `chmod`. Is there a way to do it? Please do not suggest such things like running rootless docker or anything about docker group (I have already seen this question: [How can I use docker without sudo?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/477551/how-can-i-use-docker-without-sudo) before asking mine), I am interesting only in dealing with permissions.

Comment: Setup your docker not to use sudo

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I use docker without sudo?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/477551/how-can-i-use-docker-without-sudo)

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen naah. That explains how to set it up. But he is asking why he can not use chmod 777 :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Why /var/run/docker.sock permissions are changed every time I log out? How can I forbid it?

Because the people from docker take security serious. And so should you. 
You really need to understand that this opens up your docker instance to **everyone**. [For a thorough explanation this is a must read](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/security/#docker-daemon-attack-surface). `chmod 777` is never the correct solution (well... unless the sticky bit is also set).

If you still want to do it with

```
sudo chmod 777 /var/run/docker.sock
```

you need to have this command executed each time you login. "startup applications" can be used to execute script at the time you login to the desktop. But please please do not. Use the group method below.

You can also set the immutable bit (chattr +i {file}) so normal users can not change the attributes but that is just a trick. Someone with access to the system can easily change that by rebooting with an live session; even a non admin user can do that.

> Please do not suggest such things like running rootless docker or anything about docker group, I am interesting only in dealing with permissions.

Why? You forgot to explain why these are not acceptable. In theory you could have a valid reason (though I can not imagine one myself :) ).

See [How can I use docker without sudo?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/477551/how-can-i-use-docker-without-sudo) on how to set this up or use the official documentation on how to setup docker with a [group](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/linux-postinstall/) or [rootless](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/rootless/). Those ARE the 2 methods provided by docker.

Comment: I think I had to ask this question: "How to forbid changing permissions" without mentioning docker. I want some file to have 777 permissions. I also don't want anybody to change them. Is this possible?

Comment: Set the immutable bit (`chattr +i` {file}) but even that is just a trick. Someone with access to the system can easily change that by rebooting with an live session.

Comment: looks like it is what I was looking for, thanks. It is the real answer to my question "how can i forbid changing permissions" so if you include the comment into the answer, I can accept it.

Comment: ... everyone *who can run code or commands on your computer*.

Comment: Also, I don't really understand why does this always appear in questions/answers on askubuntu and such sites: _Someone with access to the system_. There is nobody with access to my system, it is a personal computer. So I really dont care about security, all this `sudo` things and etc. I just want to make my life easier.

Comment: @sanyash not everyone lives alone. Plus this also includes external access through ssh, ftp, bugs in browsers, using any type of server with online access, malware, spyware. etc.

Comment: Your answer is not answering the question.

Answer (score 3):

Some folks on a DigitalOcean forum [suggested](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-fix-docker-got-permission-denied-while-trying-to-connect-to-the-docker-daemon-socket) a fix based on the official Docker documentation that should be more secure and permanent:

```
sudo groupadd docker
sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
newgrp docker
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change the group ownership permanently by editing `/etc/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/docker.socket`.

Set the right group at line

```
SocketGroup=docker
```

Then run `systemctl daemon-reload` and reboot