# chattr doesn't work on /run/docker.sock

Tags: 18.04, permissions, docker

From my previous [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1194205/why-var-run-docker-sock-permissions-are-changed-every-time-i-log-out-how-can-i) I got a solution that worked that time:  `sudo chattr +i /run/docker.sock`. But right now it doesn't work. I get `chattr: operation not supported while reading flags on /run/docker.sock`. Why chattr doesn't work on docker.sock anymore? How can I fix it?

Comment: Did you try this? https://superuser.com/questions/755285/why-is-chattr-and-lsattr-resulting-in-operation-not-supported-while-reading-fla

Comment: @SeverusTux I saw that question. If I understand correctly, /run/docker.sock is not a symlink. /var/run/docker.sock is.

Comment: You cant do that on socket files too. https://stackoverflow.com/a/5978150/5898324

Comment: @SeverusTux but I actually can change permissions, which doesn't correlate with that answer. `sudo chmod 777 /run/docker.sock` works just fine.

Comment: Yes. `chmod` works but `chattr` doesn't. This is true for any socket file. Try it yourself by creating a socket file `nc -lU test.sock` (or `ncat`)

Comment: @SeverusTux it is very strange because 4 months ago it worked: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1194205/why-var-run-docker-sock-permissions-are-changed-every-time-i-log-out-how-can-i?noredirect=1&lq=1 I am sure that I used `chattr +i /run/docker.sock` as suggested in the answer and comments and it worked...

Comment: @sanyash is it possible that an older package version had this placed on standard storage and now it's in RAM? I.e. different FS type?