# heroku container:login permission denied error troubleshooting question

Tags: permissions, docker, heroku

TLDR: if you have this error go here [How can I use docker without sudo?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/477551/how-can-i-use-docker-without-sudo) and once you have completed these steps restart your computer.

I am trying to push a project up to heroku. I've recently installed both docker and heroku. I've potentially made mistakes in both installs. If I run `docker -v && which docker` I get:

```
Docker version 19.03.2, build 6a30dfca031
/usr/bin/docker
```

If I recall I installed docker using a community version not `docker.io` but I'm not sure how to find out which version I installed. Either way, prior to running any docker commands I need to `sudo`.

I think I need to do the following:

[How can I use docker without sudo?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/477551/how-can-i-use-docker-without-sudo)

Also, I installed heroku for the first time on this machine and used a `snap`, which I've never used before. I had to install snaps to my path, but that appears to have been done correctly as `heroku login`

When I try to use the heroku cli and run `heroku container:login` I get:

```
Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: 
Get http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.40/version: 
dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
```

which is similar to the error I get if I just try to run `docker run hello-world` without `sudo`

```
docker: Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: 
Post http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.40/containers/create: 
dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied.
```

I "think" what I need to do is edit my docker user permissions so that the heroku cli can interact with docker correctly to run `heroku container:login`. However, prior to changing permisssions, I'd like to validate that I'm correct that the above link for "How can I use docker without sudo?" will:

1. fix my problem
2. not screw this up further

*notes*: 
running linux popos 19.10, also have the sudo problem with `docker-compose`. When I run `cat /etc/group | grep 'docker'` I get `docker:x:128:myusernamehere` however, when I run `docker run hello-world` it fails. I decided to restart, figuring that docker maybe needed to access something with the changed permission group. It worked. Now when I run `docker run hello-world` without sudo it works.

*Solution* My intuition was correct that I just needed to add permissions. `heroku container:login` works as expected now. IMO this questions should be marked as duplicate and deleted.