# I broke Ubuntu, I want to backup my data and reinstall it

Tags: data-recovery, recovery-mode, reinstall

I love Ubuntu, started using 16.04 in December. I was trying to use some terminal commands to resolve an issue with Docker, and I think that's what led to Ubuntu failing to boot thereafter.

(The main question is: How do I recover my data?)

Here are the commands I put in (with the link where I got them):

I made my user's .docker folder accessible without sudo like so:

```
sudo chgrp -hR docker ~/.docker && sudo chown -R myuser ~/.docker.
```

The `chgrp` didn't seem to help though, so probably I should only recommend the `chown` step.

[How can I use docker without sudo?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/477551/how-can-i-use-docker-without-sudo)

So I'd like to start ubuntu in recovery mode, save my data to a hard drive, and then remove and reinstall ubuntu in that partition of my hard drive.

The first step is the one I'm least sure about: How do I recover all my data?

Answer (score 1):

You can get to recovery mode by holding down left <kbd>Shift</kbd> or hitting <kbd>Esc</kbd> repeatedly as the computer boots. Here's a post from Ask Ubuntu on the process: [How can I start Ubuntu in Safe Mode?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/172319/)

Another way to do this would be to boot with a USB stick with Ubuntu use the Live mode to both mount the hard drive and plug in USB hard drive to backup needed items. You'll see both your hard drive and the USB hard drive on the desktop, you should be able to copy one from another.

Hope this helps get the needed configurations and data back.

Comment: That's a great starting point, thank you!